# JDBC exception handling: warning suppression

Tags: java, jdbc

I am currently learning some basic java SQL coding, making a basic terminal UI for my SQL project. I have been using PostgreSQL

I am using `PreparedStatement` to ensure myself from SQL injections, better be safe than sorry. `PreparedStatement` seems to always fire warnings for some reason, which I figured is a subclass to exceptions (and should get caught in the exceptions).

In my SQL triggers and functions I have created and tested the cases where I should fire exceptions, and they are all getting and working properly  catch block.

I guess using `@Supresswarnings` to let the compiler know I want to do suppress my warnings, but I might want to catch some warnings in the catch block, so I might be looking for a different solution.

The problem / question is:

1. I would like to have my prints in the try block, that is no exceptions were fired.
2. What could be done to have my prints after the execution of `preparedStmt.executeQuery` in the try block?
3. Is using `@SuppressWarnings` usually considered good coding practice when dealing with exception handling like this?
4. If I am incorrect about `preparedStatement.executeQuery()` always fires warnings, what is considered warnings in SQL language?

My code:

```
void registerStudent(Connection conn, String toBeInserted, String insertedTo)
throws SQLException{
    ResultSet res;
    String query = "INSERT INTO Registrations VALUES (?, ?)";

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, toBeInserted);
    ps.setString(2, insertedTo);

    try {
        ps.executeQuery();                        

    }catch (SQLException e) {

        SQLWarning warning = ps.getWarnings();
        if (warning != null){

        System.out.println("Yay,  insert succeeded!
    values: "+ toBeInserted +" were inserted into 
    "+insertedTo);

        }else {
            System.out.println("Nothing inserted, here goes the big exception SQL fired for ya'll: " 
         + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you even need prepared statements for your own terminal?  Statements are to prevent untrustworthy external users from injecting bad stuff into otherwise benign queries.  You should be using authentication to prevent users from issuing certain commands IMO.

Comment: Also, if your code is already mostly working, and you just want some pointers (nothing at all wrong with that), then consider perhaps posting this question to our sister site [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Please specify the warnings reported by the compiler or your IDE, so we know what you are talking about. Note that SQL Warnings are not the same as compile time / IDE warnings that you can supress with `@SupressWarning`, also note that SQL warnings can occur even with successful executions, so only checking SQL warnings in a catch block doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are still some flaws. I added also the case of an AUTOINCREMENT primary key - which you can retrieve *after* inserting.

Flaws:

- List which fields you insert, such that a later addition of a column in the database does not cause problems, and the order of columns is clear in the code.
- Use try-with-resources to close statement, result set and such, even when one returns inside, or an exception is thrown.
- Use executeUpdate for INSERT (and similar modifying operations) returning an update count.
- You catched the SQLException, which then should be rethrown, to let the caller determine what to do on gross failure.
- SQLWarnings (as does the actual SQL and the SQLException) might be interesting,
  though I not often see SQLWarnings being treated. Maybe forget it for such simple case, and instead try new SQL statements first in a separate SQL tool.

So:

```
/**
 * @return the generated primary key, the Student ID.
 */
int registerStudent(Connection conn, String toBeInserted, String insertedTo)
        throws SQLException {
    String query = "INSERT INTO Registrations(ToBeInserted, InsertedInto) VALUES(?, ?)";

    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query),
            Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) {
        ps.setString(1, toBeInserted);
        ps.setString(2, insertedTo);
        int updateCount = ps.executeUpdate();                        
        if (updateCount == 1) {
            try (ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    int id = rs.getInt(1);
                    return id;
                }
            }
            throw new SQLException("No primary key generated");
        } else {
            SQLWarning warning = ps.getWarnings();
            Logger.getLogger(Xyz.class.getName()).info("Not added, values: "
                + toBeInserted + " were not inserted into "+ insertedTo + ": " + warning);
            throw new SQLException("Not added");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much I know I really shouldn't respond to your post but it helped be a lot. I think I got confused about ps.executeQuery() and ps.executeUpdate() methods.

executeQuery() generated a warning because there was nothing being returned, although it did work to execute the update to the database with that method.

The other tips and tricks is something  I will bear with me as well.